# Weird Number patterns thinking process

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The number pattern is 
-1 , 8 , -27 , 64 , -125

Find an expression for the nth term of the sequence .

I'm been doing it by the guessing method for a few mins and couldn't get the answer . Can I get help ??

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

1. The sign is alternating.
2. Consider $n^3$.

Are you able to put these together?

Comment: Or is it a quartic expression of the form $f(x) = ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx + e$?

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote for this answer.

Comment: Quartic expression works as well but let's go for simplicity. =)
Jared brought up an important point that is there is no unique solution to such problem.

Answer (score 0):

$$-1^3 , 2^3 ,-3^3 ,4^3,-5^3$$..pattern is

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is $(-1)^nn^3$....